# how to get the substring

Tags: c#, winforms, substring

I have a string something like this `1234ABCD-1A-AB` I have separator in string[] separator , I am looping till the length of string. I want to get the `substring`. inside the loop i am writing below code

```
string tempVar = test.Substring(0, test.IndexOf("'" + separator+ "'"));
```

I tried like this as well

```
string tempVar = String.Join(",", test.Split(',').Select(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("'" + separator+ "'"))));
```

by using this I am getting error Index should not be less that 0, Loop will run only 2 times because i am loop based on separator, and I have 2 separator in my string.

let me explain:

I have a loop for separator which will execute only 2 time because I'll 2 separator one is 9th position and other one is 14th positing, inside that loop I am splitting the string based on separator

```
string[] test1 = test.Split("'" + separator+ "'");
```

in my next step I am passing one string value for next process like this

```
string temp = test1[i].ToString();
```

with this i am getting only 2 string that is `1234ABCD` and `1A` I want to get the 3rd value as well inside the loop. So I thought of taking the substring than using split.

output should be:

`first time: 1234ABCD`

`second time: 1A`

`third time: AB`

Comment: Your edits to the question are not clear. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only missing the index

```
string tempVar = test.Substring(0, test.IndexOf(separator[0].ToString()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the split function:

```
string s = "1234ABCD-1A-AB";
string[] parts = s.Split('-');
```

then:

```
s[0] == "1234ABCD"
s[1] == "1A"
s[2] == "AB"
```

---

Based on the now updated requirements, try the following:

```
string input = "1234ABCD-1A-AB";
char separator = '-';

string[] parts = input.Split(separator);

// if you do not need to know the item index:
foreach (string item in parts)
{
    // do something here with 'item'
}

// if you need to know the item index:
for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
{
    // do something here with 'item[i]', where i is 
    // the index (so 1, 2, or 3 in your case).
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Split` with your separator `'-'` and then access the returned `string[]`.

```
string[] parts = test.Split('-');
string firstPart  = parts[0];
string secondPart = parts.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
string thirdPart  = parts.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/rEzk3m)

Comment: Woharey! I have never used `ElementAtOrDefault` before. That's cool Tim! +1 of course..

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] items = str.Split(new char[] { '-' });
```

Comment: If i'll use split then how will I get 3rd value if i'll pass index of loop `string temp = test1[i].ToString();

Comment: I have given some explanation please check

Comment: Still not clear.
Try Posting your input data and your entire code.
and what is the deal with "'" + separator+ "'" (the {"'"} part)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode
>   character array.

```
string s = "1234ABCD-1A-AB";
string[] items = s.Split('-');

for(int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
  Console.WriteLine("Item number {0} is: {1}", i, items[i]);
```

Output will be;

```
Item number 0 is: 1234ABCD
Item number 1 is: 1A
Item number 2 is: AB
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/v0f0gE).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx):

```
string str = "1234ABCD-1A-AB";
string[] splitted = str.Split('-');
/* foreach (string item in splitted)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}*/
```

and you can set it as:

```
 string firstPart = splitted.FirstOrDefault();
 string secondPart = splitted.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
 string thirdPart = splitted.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Very simple via [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.split.aspx):

```
string t = "1234ABCD-1A-AB";
string[] tempVar = t.Split('-');

foreach(string s in tempVar)
{
     Console.WriteLine(s);
}
Console.Read();
```

Prints:

`1234ABCD`
`1A`
`AB`

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? @Rocky you need to layout your requirements clearly.